Firebase App Distribution - "firebase installations service is unavailable. please try again later."
For some strange reason, when I do builds via Android Studio (Either Run 'App' or Debug 'App'), everything works fine. But if I create a bundle, upload this to Firebase App Distribution, or Google Play Store Internal Testing, I suddenly get an error firebase installations service is unavailable. please try again later.
I've tried all the solutions I can find, such as readding any SHA fingerprints, redownloading google-services.json but nothing seems to work. I've never encountered this issue with any of my other apps.
Has anyone experienced this before?

were you able to resolve this issue?
